# Anonymous access on SharePoint 2016 site collection not working

Tags: sharepoint-server, anonymous-authentication, anonymous-access

I have set up anonymous on the web application level. I have created a new site collection called "X" and enabled anonymous access to the entire site level. But when I am trying to access the site it prompts me for authentication. my web application is set up with ADFS authentication as custom. IN default authentication of Web application settings I have enabled anonymous access. Can someone suggest me on this? I am using SharePoint 2016 on-premises.

Comment: Have you tried in combination with Windows Authentication instead of ADFS? Does that give same result?

Comment: other site collection works with this config. using anonymous